# How to get certain text from json object value

Tags: json, date, chart.js, fetch, react-chartjs

I am using react js. I have some json data where I am fetching the timestamp. It has date and time both. For example:

```
timestamp":"2020-03-23T14:00:00.000Z"
```

Now after fetching all the json data including timestamp. I wanna make a chart, but I only want to use the date in my chart, not the time. How do I only get the date from the timestamp in the form of 2020/03/23 not the`-` but with `/`? I am using `chartjs` for making the chart Thanks.

Edit:

```
for (const dataobj of json) {
      let tempsymbolsDate = dataobj.timestamp.split("T")[0];
      tempsymbolsDate.replace("-", "/"); //here it doesn't replace with `/` 
      console.log(tempsymbolsDate);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the string using `"2020-03-23T14:00:00.000Z".split("T")[0]` to get the date without the time.

To replace `-` characters with `/`, use the `str.replace(searchvalue, newvalue)` method. For example:
`"2020-03-23".replace(/-/g, "/")`

Edit:

```
for (const dataobj of json) {
      let tempsymbolsDate = dataobj.timestamp.split("T")[0];
      tempsymbolsDate = tempsymbolsDate.replace(/-/g, "/"); 
      console.log(tempsymbolsDate);
    }
```

Edit 2:

```
for (const dataobj of json) {
      let tempsymbolsDate = dataobj.timestamp.split("T")[0];
      tempArray = tempsymbolsDate.split("-");
      tempsymbolsDate = tempArray[2] + "/" + tempArray[1] + "/" + tempArray[0];
      console.log(tempsymbolsDate);
    }
```

Comment: @Hemlata That's strange, what happens when you try running that bit of code?

Comment: `/-/` turns red in my IDE and in console the date doesn't change the format

Comment: @Hemlata That's odd, if the problem is with the `/-/` bit, can you try running `"2020-03-23".replace("-","/").replace("-","/")` ?

Comment: I have tried that as well, but it doesn't work and instead print the date with 2020-03-23 format. I have edited my question and added some of my code if that helps.

Comment: @Hemlata Can I see a code snippet? Is it possible that you're printing a variable and haven't set the variable to the return value of the replace method?

Comment: @Hemlata Ah I see, you're calling the method, but that doesn't actually change the string. Try replacing that line with `tempsymbolsDate = tempsymbolsDate.replace(/-/g, "/");`

Comment: @Hemlata I find it very strange that it doesn't seem to work, as it has been working when I tried running it in the console. I've edited my response, can you try copy-pasting that to ensure that nothing is missing still?

Comment: Yess, it's working now. Can I also change it to format date/month/year instead of year/month/date?

Comment: @Hemlata Yes, I've edited the solution to store the numbers as an array, then print the array in reverse order. See if that works.